# ThumbnailPhoto from ActiveDirectory in Node js / Express / passport-ldapauth

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldap, ldapauth

Am working on **LDAP Active Directory** login in our system. If user is there i need to show user name, email and profile pic. Problem is that am **not getting any attribute related to profile pic from response**. After some research i found that there is one attribute called `thumbnailPhoto` that is the thumbnail Photo for user. But am not getting it in my response. I tried different code in both **activedirectory** and **passport-ldapauth** **npms** but no luck.

So currently i thought to stick with passport-ldapauth npm. And here is my code.

```
 var express = require('express')
 var app =  express();
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var multer = require('multer');
 var passport     = require('passport');
 var LdapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth');

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
     Content-Type, Accept");
     next();
 });

 var OPTS = {
     server: {
       "url": "ldap://ip-address:389",
       "bindDN": "cn=username,ou=Users,ou=user-other-ou,dc=dcname,dc=com",
       "bindCredentials": "password",
       "searchBase": "dc=dcname,dc=lan",
       "searchFilter": "(sAMAccountName={{username}})",
     },
 };

 passport.use(new LdapStrategy(OPTS));

 app.get('/api/login', function(req, res, next) {
 passport.authenticate('ldapauth', {session: false}, function(err, user, info) { 
  if (err) {
    return res.send({ success : false, message : 'authentication failed', 
   "user": [] });
  }
  if (! user) {
    return res.send({ success : false, message : 'authentication failed', "user": [] });
  }     
  return res.send({ success : true, message : 'authentication succeeded', "user": user });
})(req, res, next);
```

Where user need to give profile pic (I guess it needs to be `thumbnailPhoto`) with all other Attributes.

I tried to giving searchAttributes: `['displayName', 'mail','thumbnailPhoto']` in OPTS which will give me only given Attributes and am getting `displayName`, `mail` but not `thumbnailPhoto`.

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the photos are being stored in `thumbnailPhoto`? Have you verified this in another tool (like AD Users and Computers)?

Comment: AD will only return attributes that have values. So if you're asking for `thumbnailPhoto`, but it doesn't return it, then that tells me there is nothing there.

Comment: You where right AD was not returning any attributes related to profile pic because there was no profile pic for ldap user. Profile pic was coming from outlook not from LDAP. I checked only outlook and Skype and i thought its coming from ldap..My bad, Thanks for your time. You comment made me to think that way.

Comment: @deepakpreman did you get it implemented after you fixed your first issue? I am trying to save it to file but it doesn't like the jpg file. I eventually want to return it as part of an object (along with name, etc..) returned to the front end.

Comment: For me there was no image for user. If you are getting image from response why you are not able to bind that image with object that you want to return.